# Why does this command work when hand-written, but not when the same inputs are drawn from a data.table

Tags: r, function, syntax, data.table, mapply

**Summary:** I have two lines of code that use data.table and rbind to take an arbitrary list of rows from one table, add them to another table, then delete those rows from the origin table. I'm attempting to get this to work by drawing those inputs (origin table, destination table, list of rows) from the columns of a third table. IE instead of (pseudocode example) `table1<-rbind(table1, table2[list_of_rownums_to_copy])` I want to have it work cleanly as `table3$col1<-rbind(table3$col1, table3$col2[table3$col4])` where each row of col1 and col2 contain the names of other tables and col4 contains lists of rownumbers. This way I can wrap the commands in a function and automate running it a bunch of times using `mapply` or similar.

**In detail:**
For testing purposes I've created tables dtA through dtF. They all have the same format with a different number of rows per table. For space here is the first 6 rows of only table dtA. The other tables are teh same, they just have their letter in column "orig_table" instead of "a":

```
     val     orig_table ##dtA has "a" in this column, dtB has "b", etc
1     1          a
2     2          a
3     3          a
4     4          a
5     5          a
6     6          a
```

The following two lines of code work perfectly on any two chosen tables as long as I hand-write everything in and give a list-object:

```
dtA<- rbind(dtA, dtB[list_of_row_numbers, ])
dtB<- dtB[ -list_of_row_numbers, ]
```

In this case dtA is the destination table, dtB is the origin table, and list_of_row_numbers is a list-object containing random numbers that are taken as the row-number for which rows to select. IE the list `c(1, 3, 5)` would add rows 1, 3, 5 from table dtB to table dtA. The second line uses that same list to determine which rows to delete from dtB afterwards. It's basically the same as "cut and paste".

What I've done is create another table, named dt1, where each row is a full set of inputs for these two commands. Here is the output of `head(dt1)` for visual reference:

```
    V1     V2    V3            V4
1: dtA    dtB   5804    3500,44228,22805,47866,32495,69006,...
2: dtA    dtC   5637    59773,55783,73482,84333,57466,88604,...
3: dtA    dtD   7292    67684,90789,67507,32937,90235,83391,...
4: dtA    dtE   3321    16810,12906,40822,40316,52624,85656,...
5: dtA    dtF   4268    89944,22578,23585,95320,79005,63923,...
6: dtB    dtA   3219    46716,54828,11475,29245,76940, 2535,...
```

The first row's contents correspond to the example I've given of the hand-written command. Row 1 of Column V1 is the destination table (dtA), Row 1 Column V2 the origin table (dtB), and Row 1 Column V4 the list of which rows to work on:

```
 V1          V1   V2      V4
dtA<- rbind(dtA, dtB[list_of_row_numbers, ]) ## this copies rows from dtB to dtA
dtB<- dtB[ -list_of_row_numbers, ]   ## this deletes them from dtB afterwards
```

I'm trying to get this to accept input directly from table dt1. The end-goal is wrapping these two lines in a function to use with `mapply`, in order to iterate through the entirety of table dt1 performing each operation with the inputs listed in each row.

The problem is I can't figure out the syntax to do this. I tried simply putting in `dt1$V1` in place of `dtA` as below but it didn't work at all:

```
dt1$V1<- rbind(dt1$V1, dt1$V2[dt1[,V4])
dt1$V2<- dt1$V2[ -dt1[,V4], ]
```

I solved a similar problem before by wrapping the input in `eval(as.name(dt1$V1))`, which got a different command to properly interpret row1 col1 as the name of an object rather than just text, but it's not working here.

Comment: Sure, I'm not sure what you want the dput of though. What happens when I run the original command ```dtA<- rbind(dtA, dtB[list_of_row_numbers, ])```?

Comment: I think that was it. In the simplest possible terms: Tables dtA through dtF are the data I care about, and the tables where all the actual operations are taking place. I want to use each row of table dt1 as the "instructions". So row 1 in table dt1 says "take all the rows listed in column V4 out of the table named in column V2 and put them in the table named in column V1".  At the end of this ```dtB<- dtB[ -list_of_row_numbers, ]``` deletes the rows that were moved from the origin. It's like "cut and paste" in excel. Where can I find more about why my approach didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the rows and `assign` the objects in each row by `rbinding` the dataset with the objects from 'V2' column

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(dt1))) {

   assign(dt1$V1[i], rbind(get(dt1$V1[i]), get(dt1$V2[i])[dt1$V4[[i]],])) 
   assign(dt1$V2[i], get(dt1$V2[i])[-dt1$V4[[i]],])
 }
```

---

The columns 'V1', 'V2' have the object names stored as string. In order to update those objects in the global env, we need to `assign` the objects to a new value.  e.g.

```
v1 <- 5
assign("v1", 10)
v1
#[1] 10
```

Also, as the object names are strings, to return the value from that string, we use `get`

```
get("v1")
#[1] 10
```

In the loop, we are dynamically using the `assign` and `get` to update those objects in the global env in each iteration

Comment: As near as I can tell this is it. If it's not too much trouble can you either explain here or point me to where I can find an explanation of why this worked but my approach didn't? I'd like to understand your use of ```get()``` and ```assign()``` and why that works so differently from just inputting eg ```dt1$V1<- rbind(dt1$V1, dt1$V2[dt1[,V4])```. I have a feeling this is coming from me fundamentally missing something about how R works under the hood.

Comment: I was just testing it to verify it did work completely, I've accepted.

Comment: @D3SL i have added a simple example to make this understand.  Hope it helps for you

Comment: It does, thank you. I guess the problem with my approach was that ```eval(as.name())``` just doesn't work in certain places, so instead get/assign need to be used. The for-loop iterates over every ```i``` (ie row) in the length of ```dt1```, and since ```i``` remains the same for the duration of each loop it's functionally identical to the code I had been attempting to use. Every pair of operations is performed on the same ```i``` (row). Thank you again.

Comment: @D3SL i didn't see your `eval(as.name` approach,

Comment: I mentioned it briefly in the last paragraph because it didn't work and I assumed it must have been the wrong approach. ```eval(as.name(dt1$V1))<- rbind(eval(as.name(dt1$V1)), eval(as.name(dt1$V2))[dt1$V4, ]) ``` was where I ran out of ideas and realised I must be missing some important piece of how this works under the hood and doing things very wrong.

Comment: @D3SL in this case, `assign` is more straightforward.  Generally, I would keep the data.frames in a `list` and update those `list` elements instead of multiple objects in the global env

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210125/discussion-between-d3sl-and-akrun).